# Realm objective c - array of array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, realm

I have this features in my product json. It just the list of strings. But, they have to be localized. So, it becomes array of array.

I am not able to do Array of Array in Realm. Anyone can suggest me how can I achieve this in Realm Objective-C ?

```
{
 "name" : "Product 1",
 "features" : [
 [
  { "locale" : "en", value : "feature1"},
  { "locale" : "cn", value : "feature1 in cn"}
 ],
 [
  { "locale" : "en", value : "feature2"},
  { "locale" : "cn", value : "feature2 in cn"}
 ]
]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By modifying your JSON slightly, either at the source or as part of a mapping step in your code, you can pass it directly to Realm's KVC initialization mechanism:

```
{
  "name": "Product 1",
  "features": [
    [[
      { "locale": "en", "value": "feature1" },
      { "locale": "cn", "value": "feature1 in cn" }
    ]],
    [[
      { "locale": "en", "value": "feature2" },
      { "locale": "cn", "value": "feature2 in cn" }
    ]]
  ]
}
```

Which maps to these Realm models:

```
@interface Feature : RLMObject
@property NSString *locale;
@property NSString *value;
@end
@implementation Feature
@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Feature);

@interface FeatureList : RLMObject
@property RLMArray<Feature> *features;
@end
@implementation FeatureList
@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(FeatureList);

@interface Product : RLMObject
@property NSString *name;
@property RLMArray<FeatureList> *features;
@end
@implementation Product
@end
```

At this point, you can deserialize the JSON into a dictionary and initialize your Realm object graph with this:

```
NSDictionary *productDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"product" withExtension:@"json"]] options:0 error:nil];
[Product createInDefaultRealmWithValue:productDictionary];
```

Which gives you the following object graph:

```
[0] Product {
  name = Product 1;
  features = RLMArray <0x7fe43366be00> (
    [0] FeatureList {
      features = RLMArray <0x7fec3a772c10> (
        [0] Feature {
          locale = en;
          value = feature1;
        },
        [1] Feature {
          locale = cn;
          value = feature1 in cn;
        }
      );
    },
    [1] FeatureList {
      features = RLMArray <0x7fec3a773d20> (
        [0] Feature {
          locale = en;
          value = feature2;
        },
        [1] Feature {
          locale = cn;
          value = feature2 in cn;
        }
      );
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: where should I put featureLists in json?

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your latest edits in your question

Comment: can we change Realm model side instead of json?

Comment: because json is from api. it's a bit weird for other platforms to consume this json since it is optimized for realm.

Comment: I suggest you use a model mapping framework like Mantle or KZPropertyMapper

Comment: I am stuck with your code.Could you please help me because I face  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Property 'statusReasons' requires a protocol defining the contained type - example: RLMArray<Person>.' error?

Comment: First I upvoted your answer as it was easy.Now I face above error.Help me